# Enumeration for C++ shows an error: "A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object."

Tags: c++, class, enums, enumeration

So, i am writing a code to calculate the amount based on bank transaction.
I created an enumeration class to identify the SALE = 1, VALUEADDED = 2, CREDIT = 3, CANCEL = 4, PROMO = 5, DISCOUNT =6, and INTERTERRITORY = 7.

This is a class for transaction, the TransactionType is the enumeration.

```
class transaction {
public:
    enum class TransactionType { sale = 1, valueadded, credit, cancel, promo, discount, interterritory };
    transaction(int transactionId, int salerepId, int transactionType, int amount) {
        this->transactionId = transactionId;
        this->salerepId = salerepId;
        this->transactionType = static_cast<TransactionType>(transactionType);
        this->amount = amount;
    }

    void print() {
        cout << transactionId << "\t\t" << salerepId << "\t\t";
        switch (transactionType)
        {
        case TransactionType::sale:
            cout << "SALE";
            break;
        case TransactionType::valueadded:
            cout << "VALUEADDED";
            break;
        case TransactionType::credit:
            cout << "CREDIT";
            break;
        case TransactionType::cancel:
            cout << "CANCEL";
            break;
        case TransactionType::promo:
            cout << "PROMO";
            break;
        case TransactionType::discount:
            cout << "DISCOUNT";
            break;
        case TransactionType::interterritory:
            cout << "INTERTERRIOTY";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "UNIDENTIFIED";
            break;
        }
        cout << "\t\t" << amount << endl;
    }
    TransactionType transactionType;
private:
    int transactionId;
    int salerepId;
    int amount;

};
```

The code below is what i want to calculate the amount based on what type of transaction is. (Territory_output is an another class that gives the output of the amount, and salerep::amount is an another instance from a different class that gives the initial amount).

```
territory_output tAmount;
if (transaction::transactionType == transaction::TransactionType::sale) {
    tAmount.territoryAmount += salerep::amount * 1.1;
    return tAmount.territoryAmount;
}
if (transaction::transactionType == transaction::TransactionType::valueadded) {
    tAmount.territoryAmount += salerep::amount  * 1.1;
    return tAmount.territoryAmount;
}
if (transaction::transactionType == transaction::TransactionType::credit) {
    tAmount.territoryAmount -= salerep::amount * 1;
    return tAmount.territoryAmount;
}
if (transaction::transactionType == transaction::TransactionType::cancel) {
    tAmount.territoryAmount -= salerep::amount * 1.25;
    return tAmount.territoryAmount;
}
if (transaction::transactionType == transaction::TransactionType::promo) {
    tAmount.territoryAmount -= salerep::amount * 0;
    return tAmount.territoryAmount;
}
if (transaction::transactionType == transaction::TransactionType::discount) {
    tAmount.territoryAmount -= salerep::amount  *1.1;
    return tAmount.territoryAmount;
}
if (transaction::transactionType == transaction::TransactionType::interterritory) {
    tAmount.territoryAmount += salerep::amount *0.75;
    return tAmount.territoryAmount;
}
```

I am getting an error "A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object." for calling transaction::TransactionType as enumeration.
and i am getting the same error "A nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object." for salerep::amount.
Can someone help please?
This is a picture for the table which tells the attribution.[The table of Transaction Type & Attribution Rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8EcI.png)

Comment: it's not the `enum` - your `transaction` class does not have a `static` member named `transactionType`

Comment: what do you want to refer to with `transaction::transactionType` ?

Answer (score 0):

`transaction::transactionType` would be a valid expression had `transactionType` been a `static` member of the class. Since `transactionType` is a non-`static` member of the class, you can use only in the context of object.

E.g.

```
transaction tr;
if (tr.transactionType == transaction::TransactionType::sale) {
```

You haven't shown the definition of the class `salerep` but I am guessing `salerep::amount` suffers from the same problem. You need an object of type `salerep` and access its member using the `.` syntax.

```
salerep rep;

...

if (tr.transactionType == transaction::TransactionType::sale) {
    tAmount.territoryAmount += rep.amount * 1.1;
    return tAmount.territoryAmount;
}
```

Comment: so, do i state `transaction tr;` in class or in main function.

Comment: @SidaZhang, I don't know how to answer that question without a [mcve].